# Prevent 'Display' window from appearing after pressing 'Turn on/off display' shortcut in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, display, xfce

I have an Acer laptop and it has a shortcut (Fn + F6) to turn the display on/off. This is very useful, however I've faced one annoying issue: every time I press this shortcut, the 'Display' window (where you can change resolution, frame rate etc.) appears and I have to close it every time.

Is there a way to prevent this window from opening after the shortcut pressing?

Acer Aspire V3-571G, Xubuntu Studio 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, with @clearkimura's help:

1. Go to `Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Application Shortcuts`
2. Look for command `xfce4-display-settings --minimal` with shortcut `XF86Display`
3. Remove it

Comment: Please mark your question as solved.